# Pager template along with NumericPagerField

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to use Pager template and to bind the content of NumericPagerField to the pager template.

Desired Pager:(unable to post image as i dont have 10 points )

Expand/Collapse -----------------------------------------------Page <1 2 3 4>

On ASPX Page:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="ItemDataPager">
<Fields>
    <asp:TemplatePagerField>
        <PagerTemplate>
            <asp:Panel>
            Panel to create expand and collapse all
            </asp:Panel>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton> Previous</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Panel ID="NumericPagerPlaceHolder"></asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton>Next</asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </PagerTemplate>
    </asp:TemplatePagerField>
    <asp:NumericPagerField />
</Fields>
```

On aspx.cs

I need to write a code which gets the content from "NumericPagerField" and places in the "Panel" inside the table of "PagerTemplate"

I tried this way

```
    DataPager dataPager = ((e.Item.FindControl("ItemDataPager")) as DataPager);
    Control numericPagerControl = dataPager;
    Control numericPagerPlaceHolder = dataPager.FindControl("NumericPagerPlaceHolder");
    numericPagerPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(numericPagerControl);
```

In the second line i was unable to find method which gives content of "NumericPagerPlaceHolder"
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not solving your classic ASP question but for the headache you will go through using built in ASP.NET controls (I'm sorry for your luck not being able to use MVC3) you would be just as quick to write a quick `[WebMethod]`  and use JQGrid and JQuery to accomplish your goals.

JQGrid:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Then to capture your data you can hook into $.ajax in JQuery.  This will make your page ajax driven if that isn't a restriction for you, it will be 10x easier in the end to actually do what you need to do and to maintain long term.

$.ajax documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

How to build a JSon object to return that will bind data to a grid (Your method will return a string):

```
return Json(
    (
        new
        {
            total = totalPages /*calculate this total records / rowsPerPage */,
            page = page /* passed in by jqgrid */,
            records = YourCollection.Count(),
            rows =
                YourCollection.Select(x => new
                {
                    i = x.RowIdentifier,
                    cell = new[]
                            {
                                x.YourProperty,
                x.YourOtherProperty,
                x.YourOtherOtherProperty,
                x.YouGetThePointProperty
                            }
                }
                ).ToArray()
        }
    )
    , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Honestly when you start trying to do some of the quirky stuff with dynamic data binding, paging, and updates you're really best going outside the built in asp.net objects and going custom.

**EDIT** (Adding some details wrt actually using the asp:DataPager):

If you absolutely must use the asp:DataPager you can dig into this very informative blog which covers everything you are trying to do,  https://web.archive.org/web/20201202211045/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061009-1.aspx.

~Vulgarbinary